# Sharing virtualenv across two projects

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have my global installation of python, lets call it global env. Then I have a project (lets call is project_X) that I contribute to which uses olders versions of numeric modules. I use virtualenv in order to have for example pandas 0.20 installed on global env but pandas 0.18 on project X env.

Now I want to create a project of my own (lets call it myproj) which will import project X as a module. For the sake of simplicity I will use in myproj the same dependencies as project X. Even so, how exactly do I:

A) tell that myproj and project X should use the same virtualenv? I mean, regarding virtualenv the only things I know is to do venv/bin/activate and deactivate. Inside project X's folder I have a venv folder, so in myproj I would have a venv folder... how should I tell virtualenv these are the same?

B) tell myproj, which is in a folder ~/myproj that when I do import project X I mean the folder in ~/project X?

Comment: Keep your environment outside your project folder and share it that way.

Comment: Do you understand what happens when you activate an environment? I think that is a big part of the confusion here.

Comment: @MadPhysicist No, I don't.

Comment: You set up your environment variables and configuration files to point to a particular version of Python and a particular set of installed packages. If you just activate your projectX environment, you should be good to go within that shell for any other project with the same dependencies.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Got it. Thank you. That's actually not enough because projectX is not in site-packages or anywhere in `sys.path`. However your answer lead me in the right direction. I just added projectX to `sys.path` (this is in addition to projectX's venv).

Answer (score 0):

I used [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) to solve that issue.

- Create a virtualenv by running `pipenv install` at `project_X`
- Make a symbolic link to the generated virtualenv to a folder `.venv` within `myproj`. e.g `ln -s {your_home_folder}/.local/share/virtualenvs/your_projectX_virtualenv .venv`